# How to sum the (pattern - 00h 00m 00.000s) time information in a column in google spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, datetime, google-sheets

I have a column in my excel/google spreadsheet with data of the pattern 00h 00m 00.000s . that is hours minutes and seconds data. I would like a total value (summation) of the values in the column and get the total hours mins seconds value.

I could do this by splitting the column values summing individual columns and then adding them. But I wanna know if there is any better efficient formula available.

Sample Data

```
CoL
00h 02m 36.947s
00h 01m 37.988s
00h 02m 52.138s
00h 03m 31.210s
00h 03m 11.153s
```

Total = Need Total related formula Here

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to seconds separately in a adjacent column with a formula

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,1,2))*3600+VALUE(MID(A1,5,2))*60+VALUE(MID(A1,9,6))
```

Then you can reach to the standard format by using `=SUM(B1:B5)/86400` and converting to the time format (in the ribbon)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, formatted as Duration (with milliseconds):

```
 =ArrayFormula(sum(1*left(regexreplace(A1:A,"[hms]",":"),14)))
```

assuming data is in ColumnA.